# String Or Binary Data Would Be Truncated - Column is Big Enough

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a confusing issue. I have a WPF application that is using a local SQL Server Database. I am using Entity Framework. I'm trying to store a byte array of length 120 into a BINARY(120) column.

The data should fit, but for some reason I keep getting the error, 'String or binary data would be truncated'.

The table structure looks like this:

```
Column_name   Type        Computed   Length

Id            int         no         4
Foo           varchar     no         500
Bar           binary      no         120
```

As an experiment, I tried altering the column to be a VARBINARY(MAX) column, however even in that case I still get the same error. This would usually indicate that another column could be causing the problem, however I know the problem is not the Id column, and the string I'm storing into Foo is "test string", which is obviously small enough.

The method that is inserting into the database isn't doing anything special:

```
public void Create(FooEntry entry)
{
    _context.FooEntries.Add(entry);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something really obvious, but how should I go about fixing this issue?

**Update:**

Yes, I am quite sure the EDMX and the database table is in sync (because when I update the database table, I always refresh the edmx).

I attempted to manually insert a byte array of length 120 into the table, and did not get the error. When I manually inserted a byte array of length 121, the 'String or binary data would be truncated' error occurred, which is the correct behavior.

The byte array that I was attempting to insert while debugging the program was this value:

```
 '0x2400320061002400310030002400510078004400310072003400390079004C006D0041004A00760049004E005700730069007900490058004F007400740052007600500031006900700078004C0044007000610032004900350038007700310059002E0071003300680033004B0064002F00430074005700'
```

which is a byte array of length 120.

**Update 2:**

I ran SQL Server Profiler and it gave me the following SQL query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[FooEntry]([Foo], [Bar])
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[FooEntry]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()',N'@0 varchar(500),@1 binary(120)',@0='test string',@1=0x24003200610024003100300024004100420047007400560056006A0076004D006F006500770036005000300054004D002F006B007800740075007A00490036004F004400660047004A0062004E0069004E00790041007A0051006A0058004300660072007400360051007A0043004B004400580075006500
```

Very weird. This query works when I execute it manually, but EF throws an error when this query is executed while the program is running.

Comment: is this entity framework?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question accordingly

Comment: Just to clarify, your ID is 2,147,483,647 or less, your Foo is "test string" and your Bar is a byte array of length 120?

Comment: How is your EF configured, EDMX or Fluent/code-first?  Can we see the mapping configuration?

Comment: try to insert data manually in SQL Server. It might help you in tracking the issue.

Comment: Did you validate the SQL connection to make sure you works against the correct database? 
When the data is to large for the column, EF would throw an EntityValidationError. But you get an SQL error which usually means the DB and de EDMX are out of sync

Comment: @MethodMan trailing spaces in a byte array are uncommon..

Comment: @Grax Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @SamParsons I meant to state it as Trailing Null Bytes

Comment: @Luc Yes, I am working against the correct database. I am quite sure the edmx and the database are not out of sync, as every time I update the FooEntry table in the database, I also refresh the FooEntry table in the edmx.

Comment: @Ankush Jain I will give that a shot and let you know what happens.

Comment: @AnkushJain I attempted to insert a byte array of length 120 manually into the database table, and it worked correctly. When I tried inserting a byte array of length 121, I got the 'string or binary data would be truncated' error. So it seems like the length of 120 constraint is working correctly.

Comment: Have you used SQL Server Profiler to see exactly what is being sent to SQL Server?

Comment: @DanForbes Yes. I have the posted the query above in my question update.

Comment: @SamParsons - if I'm reading your edit correctly, what you posted is not really what I asked for. I've run into issues that stemmed from the fact that what was actually being executed on SQL Server was different than what I expected based on what was happening in my C# code. This is why I asked about using SQL Server Profiler to see _exactly_ what is being sent to SQL Server. Edit: I missed your update; mea culpa.

Comment: Have you tried [looking at the error in SQL Server Profiler](https://slishnevsky.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-the-statement-has-been-terminated/)?

Comment: @DanForbes I tried what was suggested in the article you posted. I looked in the "Exception" EventClass and it gave me the same message "String or binary data would be truncated." RPC:Starting gave me the exact query that I posted above.

Comment: check the properties of the binary column in the edmx model. Look for "length" attribute and see if it is 120

Comment: @FabioLuz Yes, max length for the binary column is set to 120

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally figured out the problem, and the answer is ridiculous.

There were two databases in my project directory, DatabaseA and DatabaseB that had the same schema. Entity Framework was running queries against DatabaseA, however my EDMX was pointing to DatabaseB, and the database that was showing in my Server Explorer was DatabaseB.

This issue probably occurred while I was fixing an issue I had earlier that was causing my local SQL Server database data to be overwritten with each build.

My advice for anybody that is running into this issue is to make sure your app.config files in your Solution all have connection strings that are pointing to the same database. The way I fixed this problem was to update the connection string in my data layer:

1) I removed the connection string in my app.config file

2) In my EDMX designer, I deleted my FooEntry table and then right-clicked and selected 'Update Model from Database'. Then a dialog popped up that allowed me to create a new connection string. Through this dialog, you can browse for the correct database and Visual Studio will make the correct connection string for you.